# Strange Size difference in android internal storage vs external storage

Tags: android, memory, difference, android-external-storage, internal-storage

I am trying to save some images downloaded from internet during runtime into external storage so that I can read them directly instead of downloading again.
Everything is working well except the fact that it is taking too much space.
If I store same images in internal storage, it takes only about 300kb, but for external storage, it is taking nearly 1.7mb.

Can someone explain why this is happening.

This is the code I am using for storing the file in the external storage.

```
public void saveImage(Context ctx, Bitmap b,String name){ //for external storage
    FileOutputStream out;
    try {
        File file = new File(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(null), name);
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Following one is used for storing the file in internal storage

```
public void saveImage(Context ctx, Bitmap b,String name){
    FileOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = ctx.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This method is called from same place both the time but when I check the memory used, there is a huge difference.

I am searching for last 2 days but didn't find anything about this issue.
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: How do compare the sizes of the files? Are the contents (raw bytes) of the two files identical?

Comment: I can't access file directly outside of my app in case of internal storage, so file comparison is not possible.
I am just going to android settings->apps->my app
and checking memory there as listed by android

Comment: Well, then it's not the precise numbers, to say the least. Anything can cause such difference in **memory usage**, since many other apps may write to SD and internal storage at the same time. You shall compare sizes directly, for example, by running your app on emulator.

Comment: How can other apps writing to storage affect the memory listed under my app?
I tried in the emulator, there memory comes to more or less same.
The location returned by getExternalFilesDir is private to my app according to the official docs
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Please help me understand why is it changing then?

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake - I didn't notice "settings->apps->my app". Anyway, I would recommend you to compare the files explicitly, just to eliminate other factors. And it's actually easy to do: 1) with emulator, 2) by copying the file programmatically from internal storage to the external one.